# Select query within more than 150 different conditions in where clause

Tags: sql-server, select, where-clause

I have a table in my SQL Server database which has more than 400000 rows and I want to select the full names that starts with several names that are in a .txt file approximately more than 150 name, so how would the query will be inside my command in C# .. I could write it in this way but it will be too long and may create a delay or some kind of bugs !

```
select * 
from tableName 
where fullName like '%Jack%' 
   or fullName like '%Wathson%' 
   --.... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

First, SQL Server can handle very long queries. I have created queries that are at least 150k characters, and they work without problem. The limit is considerably larger than that.

Second, you are correct that a bunch of `like` statements is going to take a long time. There is overhead to `like`.

Third, your patterns do not conform to your statement. If you want names that *start* with a particular pattern, then remove the wildcard from the beginning of the pattern. This has the added benefit that SQL Server can use a regular index on `FullName` for the match.

Finally, if you are really looking at initial strings, then you might want to consider a full text index (here is one place to [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql)). These are usually more efficient than using `like`.